# Why is rv32gc optimising branchless code with branches for RISC-V?

Tags: gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, riscv, branch-prediction

Let's attempt to define a function that returns the maximum of two values x and y. A sufficient condition for these formulas to be valid is that, for signed integers, `–2^30 <= x, y <= 2^30 – 1`, and for unsigned integers, `0 <= x, y <= 2^31 – 1` (*i.e.,* it is only required to work on a reduced integer range of effectively one bit less). The most universal (and straightforward) implementation would be:

```
int max(int x, int y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y
}
```

Up until the Pentium Pro, this would be the generated assembly in x86:

```
max:  # GCC -O3 -march=pentium -m32
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
  cmp eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
  jge .L4
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
.L4:
  ret
```

But starting with the Pentium Pro, a new instruction `CMOVcc r32,r/m` was introduced, that performs a conditional move depending on some specified status flags:

> The CMOVcc instructions check the state of one or more of the status
> flags in the EFLAGS register (CF, OF, PF, SF, and ZF) and perform a
> move operation if the flags are in a specified state (or condition). A
> condition code (cc) is associated with each instruction to indicate
> the condition being tested for. If the condition is not satisfied, a
> move is not performed and execution continues with the instruction
> following the CMOVcc instruction. These instructions can move a 16- or
> 32-bit value from memory to a general-purpose register or from one
> general-purpose register to another. Conditional moves of 8-bit
> register operands are not supported. The terms "less" and "greater"
> are used for comparisons of signed integers and the terms "above" and
> "below" are used for unsigned integers.

This allows the creation of a *branchless* maximum function (if you don't know why a branchless implementation is generally a good thing, you might need to read a little bit about [instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining)):

```
max:  # GCC -O3 -march=pentiumpro -m32
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
  cmp eax, edx
  cmovl eax, edx
  ret
```

With the function calling conventions of x86-64, this is further simplified to:

```
max:  # GCC -O3 
  cmp esi, edi
  mov eax, edi
  cmovge eax, esi
  ret
```

---

Are there other architectures whose compilers produce branchless max/min functions? Well, here's the code for ARMv7:

```
max:  # CLANG -O3
  cmp r0, r1
  movle r0, r1
  bx lr
```

ARMv8-a and ARM64 have a quite *interesting* instruction:

```
max:  # GCC -O3
  cmp w1, w0
  csel w0, w1, w0, ge
  ret
```

What about RISC-V? Well, there seems to be no equivalent of *conditional moves*, so the compiler generates the basic branch-based version:

```
max:  # rv32gc clang -O3
  blt a1, a0, .LBB1_2
  mv a0, a1
.LBB1_2:
  ret
```

---

Can we do better? In [Hacker’s Delight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker%27s_Delight), Warren presents us the following formula that works in the aforementioned range (*i.e.,* on a reduced integer range of one bit less) without any branches. In C:

```
int max_v1(int x, int y) {
    return (x - ((x-y) & ((x-y) >> 31)));
}
```

Where `>>` should stand for arithmetic (signed) shift right. The hand-written RISCV assembly for this function is just 4 instructions:

```
max_v1:  # hand-written
  sub a1, a0, a1
  srai a2, a1, 31
  and a1, a1, a2
  sub a0, a0, a1
  ret
```

---

It’s interesting to analyse how this is compiled to x86-64. Because the function only works in the range defined, it is not *exactly* the same as the maximum. But the optimiser doesn’t exactly produce what we would be expecting:

```
max_v1:  # Clang -O1
  mov eax, edi
  xor ecx, ecx
  mov edx, edi
  sub edx, esi
  cmovns edx, ecx
  sub eax, edx
  ret
```

It’s branchless alright, though it depends on the *conditional move.* How is this compiled for the RISCV?

```
max_v1:  # rv32gc clang -O3
  sub a2, a0, a1
  bltz a2, .LBB0_2
  mv a1, a0
.LBB0_2:
  mv a0, a1
  ret
```

Wait, what? We have a branch! Four instructions and a branch. Why? Let’s take a peek at the unoptimised version:

```
max_v1:  # rv32gc clang -O0
  addi sp, sp, -16
  sw ra, 12(sp)
  sw s0, 8(sp)
  addi s0, sp, 16
  sw a0, -12(s0)
  sw a1, -16(s0)
  lw a0, -12(s0)
  lw a1, -16(s0)
  sub a1, a0, a1   # <
  srai a2, a1, 31  # <
  and a1, a1, a2   # <
  sub a0, a0, a1   # <
  lw ra, 12(sp)
  lw s0, 8(sp)
  addi sp, sp, 16
  ret
```

If you ignore all the stack manipulation (because the compiler isn’t optimising for using the `a` registers for function parameters), lines `10-13` are precisely the code we’ve manually produced. Why, oh why, is the optimiser, in all its wisdom, introducing a branch?

---

P.S. I have a theory, but I would first love to hear from the experts.

Comment: Compilers are sometimes able to disentangle bithack idioms back into some internal representation of the logic, and then materialize it again in a "straightforward" way  (like [how they see through xor-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382441/why-is-the-xor-swap-optimized-into-a-normal-swap-using-the-mov-instruction)).  On RISC-V that means with a branch for this.  That may be what's going on.

Comment: RISC-V extension B (https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-bitmanip/draft/bitmanip.html) has conditional move (and a bunch of other standard bit-manipulation stuff like popcnt, clz / ctz, rotates, byte-reverse, sign-extend byte and halfword.  And fun stuff like andn, xorn, orn, carryless multiply, min/max, horizontal OR inverted within bytes (like like `pcmpeqb` against zero, useful for strlen/strcpy), single-bit clear/extract/invert like x86 `bts`/`btr reg, reg|imm`, shift-left-and-add like x86 `lea reg, [reg+reg*2,4,or 8]` )

Comment: Hrm, that link I found doesn't mention `cmov`, but my answer on  [RISCV branchless coding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72340698) shows clang `-march=rv32gcb0p93` using `cmov`.  (Extension C and B version 0.93).  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riscv/riscv-bitmanip/master/bitmanip-draft.pdf (B version 0.94) shows `cmov` as part of the Zbt subset of it.  And seems extension B has many more parts, including byte and nibble shuffles with a variable control, like `pshufb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang makes this transform for x86-sans-cmov as well: try `clang -m32 -march=i486 -O2`. It results from how LLVM optimization pipeline works.

For such small testcases, you can easily inspect how the compiler transforms the code on your own. On Compiler Explorer, select "Add New > LLVM Opt Pipeline" in the compiler pane; it will spawn a new pane showing the sequence of compiler passes, with passes that changed the code highlighted in green: https://godbolt.org/z/8jEq1nxGY

You can see that LLVM's InstCombine pass recognized the sequence of instructions

```
%sub = sub nsw i32 %x, %y
%shr = ashr i32 %sub, 31
%and = and i32 %sub, %shr
%sub2 = sub nsw i32 %x, %and
ret i32 %sub2
```

and replaced it with

```
%sub2 = call i32 @llvm.smax.i32(i32 %x, i32 %y)
ret i32 %sub2
```

And then at the beginning of machine code generation passes, the `smax` instrinsic was expanded to a branchy sequence.

Note that unlike Clang, GCC 12 emits the desired branchless code (it doesn't pattern-match this expression):

```
sub     a1,a0,a1
srai    a5,a1,31
and     a5,a5,a1
sub     a0,a0,a5
ret
```

Comment: `CMOVcc` in x86 was added since i686, so obviously if you compile for i486 it can't use those instructions

Comment: @phuclv: yes, I'm well aware, and that's exactly the point: the behavior is not specific to rv32gc, it is reproducible on other architectures where LLVM lacks a branchless expansion for min/max