# How to compile for riscv zicond extension in gcc?

Tags: gcc, riscv, instruction-set

I wanted to use zicond extension for risc-v architecture. I read [those messages](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/list/?series=341354). I couldn't understand how to compile for zicond extension. I tried in [godbolt 1](https://godbolt.org/z/xjaEv9sE3) and [godbolt 2](https://godbolt.org/z/xn1zEfo8f) with different march flags. However, both didn't produce a conditional operation.

Could you help me to get a GCC which is developed for zicond? (I have done it for llvm(clang), but I wonder for GCC )

Comment: For clang, see [RISCV branchless coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77161000) .  IDK if `-march=rv64gc_zicond1p0` or `-march=rv64gc_zicond` works in GCC, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC13.2 isn't new enough.  14.0.0 will be, but isn't released yet.

gcc (trunk 14.0.0 20231022) on Godbolt does use `czero.eqz` when you compile with `-march=rv64gc_zicond` or `-march=rv64gc_zicond1p0` (https://godbolt.org/z/xod75bTEK).

Clang still needs `-menable-experimental-extensions` and the option with a version number (1p0)

Future readers: see [RISCV branchless coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340698/riscv-branchless-coding/77161000#77161000) for more about the current state of Zicond and other stuff that was going to be part of extension B before that got split up.

Comment: Thnak you for clear answer. How to see the possible march flags? This version of zicond is not converting even the little complex ones as I understand here https://godbolt.org/z/WbcGf1z89

Or is this a compiler's lack of optimization?

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL: Selecting between two non-zero values takes two `czero` instructions and an `or`, so it would have to do that twice to select which base address and which data to store.  If its cost-model thinks branches are cheap enough, it's reasonable for compilers not to do if-conversion in that case.  Even for AArch64, which has excellent conditional-select instructions, GCC and clang choose to make branchy asm (https://godbolt.org/z/baMYra4sY).

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL https://godbolt.org/z/7Mbj1KG8d shows GCC and clang for x86-64 also making branchy asm.  They make branchless asm only when auto-vectorizing with masked stores (AVX2 or AVX-512 https://godbolt.org/z/Mqrhv4sTn, unfortunately even with `-march=znver3` where AVX2 masked stores are very slow).  x86-64 GCC nightly builds do support APX (`-mapxf`), but the optimizer doesn't use conditional stores for this.

Comment: I need to compile coremark with Zicond but cormark is a collection of c codes So I think I cannot use Godbolt for this porpuse. I wanted to get gnu riscv compiler with gcc 14. How to build it? I didn't create any other question because it is the continuation of the same question.

Comment: I switched gcc branch from  13.0 to trunk branch. and riscv-gnu-toolchain is in master branch. I compiled toolchain successfully but it gives error when I compile coremark.
Error is "stdio.h: No such file or directory" I thought I couldn't compile the toolchain correctly.

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL: Perhaps your RISC-V toolchain is targeting freestanding rather than Linux?  But the "gnu" might indicate GNU/Linux with glibc?  stdio.h is part of libc, not the toolchain proper.  When you configure your RISC-V GCC, you might need to tell it the right include paths for your RISC-V headers and libraries to match how your 13.0 cross-compiler was configured.  Check `riscv-...-gcc  -v` to see its config options.

Comment: yes, I am using `riscv64-unknown-elf-` I changed all the repos to the master branch now. I couldn't compile the file including a single function same as the code in `godbolt` link above. Fortunately, I was able to compile Coremark with zicond extension. This make me think I made a mistake in the compiler flag. I cannot paste the config options because I overwrite new compiler over the old compiler (Old is only gcc submodule is master. Others are in the last branch in riscv-gnu-toolchain. New is the master branch for all submodules of riscv-gnu-toolchain).

Comment: The action to solve that error should be checking out the glibc submodule branch from tag 13.0 to master. (I am not sure.)